# Undefined variable inside textboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql

As you can see I'm having an error inside my texboxes. Can anyone help me fix this error?

Errors inside the textboxes are the following:

```
**

> aic:

**
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: aic in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: aic in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: aic in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br />
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: aic in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />

**

> Name List:

** 
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br />
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>43</b><br />
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />

> **Address:**

<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: address in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>48</b><br />
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: address in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>49</b><br />
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: address in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>50</b><br />
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: address in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php</b> on line <b>51</b><br />
```

php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['code'])){
include('include/connect.php');

$batchcode = $_POST['code'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT aic,batchcode,address,name FROM tb_app WHERE batchcode LIKE '$batchcode'");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $aic[] = $rows['aic'];
    $name[] = $rows['name'];
    $address[] = $rows['address'];
}
}
?>
```

html code:

```
Search Batchcode:<input type="text" name="code" id="query" /><br />
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
aic: <br />
<input type="text" name="optA1" value="<?php echo $aic[0] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optA2" value="<?php echo $aic[1] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optA3" value="<?php echo $aic[2] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optA4" value="<?php echo $aic[3] ?>" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Name List: <br />
<input type="text" name="optB1" value="<?php echo $name[0] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optB2" value="<?php echo $name[1] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optB3" value="<?php echo $name[2] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optB4" value="<?php echo $name[3] ?>" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Address: <br />
<input type="text" name="optC1" value="<?php echo $address[0] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optC2" value="<?php echo $address[1] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optC3" value="<?php echo $address[2] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optC4" value="<?php echo $address[3] ?>" /> <br />
</td>
</form>
```

I dont want my textboxes to be looped because each of them have unique name that ill be using with my javascript in the future.

Comment: The notice is pretty self explanatory. What results are you getting from the database?

Comment: This is what your code will produce if your query does not return any rows. You should check if your query returned rows before trying to generate output based on the assumption that it did.

Comment: @Sammitch what should i do then? what condition should i put if rows dont generate output?

Comment: You can give them unique names even with a loop. Anyway, if you define your array outside of the mysql loop then you might see that it's simply empty, perhaps because nothing was selected.

Comment: @Jonast92 yes until i type a batchcode in the batchcode(textbox) it will not be longer empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this errors appears when you try to echo  a variable that is not defined, in this case, it means that your code doesn't enter in `while` loop, **and** this means that your query result is **empty**.

Try :

```
if($sql) {
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $aic[] = $rows['aic'];
        $name[] = $rows['name'];
        $address[] = $rows['address'];
    }
}else {
    $aic     = array('empty','empty','empty','empty');
    $name    = array('empty','empty','empty','empty');
    $address = array('empty','empty','empty','empty');
}
```

By the way, I think you want this query and missing the `%` before or after `$batchcode`, you can try this too :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT aic,batchcode,address,name FROM tb_app 
WHERE batchcode LIKE '%".$batchcode."%'");
```

OR this :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT aic,batchcode,address,name FROM tb_app 
    WHERE batchcode = '".$batchcode."'");
```

Comment: It's also important to understand the code and how it can vary between your project and another's.

Comment: @Alireza Fallah all of them :(...my code has a search function to the batchcode like a live search using ajax to find all the batchcodes.

Comment: @Alireza Fallah i solved the error thanks for the codes i got the idea on it :D

Answer (score 0):

I see you are looking in a table based on a batchcode, so if you are looking for that exact batchcode use =

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT aic,batchcode,address,name FROM tb_app WHERE batchcode = '".$batchcode."'");
```

Comment: Correct the placing of double and single quote at the end of the SQL. These seem to have interchanged. Have a look.